# Receive some general information about the incoming user to our webpage

Tags: google-cloud-platform

we need to know some general data about the user entered on our webpage. Like the range of age (e.g. 18-24), gender, favorite color, country, etc. Is there any way to receive this information From Google, Facebook, or other social network services (free or paid)?

Comment: If you are using Google, etc and the user authenticates to your site and the user grants permission, yes, some information is available. This varies based upon the Identity Provider.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, How can I get those details?? And we do not using Google, we need some general data from users who log in to the browser. Is it possible??

Comment: Review the documentation for the Identity Provider that you plan to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you properly this is regarding access to public data.I will try to give some information on this.

Considering Google Cloud Platform and accessing public data via the Google Cloud Console, you must authenticate with Google.You can authenticate with any Google account; the account does not have to be associated with the project that contains the public data, nor does it need to be signed up for the Cloud Storage service.

By contrast, accessing public data with gsutil or a Cloud Storage API link does not require authentication. These methods are suited for general-purpose links to publicly shared data. For example, an API link can be used in a web page, with client libraries, or with a command-line tool such as cURL. You can see more details on [Accessing public data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data).

From another point of view and considering your case, it seems like details on [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics) might be helpful for you, since it can  analyze in-depth details about the visitors on your website.You can also take a look at [Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/?hl=en#topic=3544906).